# JQuery autocomplete not working in IE8 -unable to get value from response

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have autocomplete on one textbox. it's working in IE9, firefox, chrome. but not working in IE8.
error msg is :SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'question': object is null or undefined.
please read the following code and comments inside. Thanks.

```
    $(function () {
    $newdiv.find("input[id$=tbxQuestion]").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Services/Questions.ashx",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    type: "tf",
                    maxRows: 10,
                    name_startsWith: request.term

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.questions, function (q) {
                        //q has values right before here  
                        return {//q is undefined here. try to find the reason.
                            value:q.question,
                            answer:q.answer,
                            opta: q.opta,
                            optb: q.optb,
                            optc: q.optc,
                            optd: q.optd
                        }
                    }))
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 4,
        delay: 800,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);


            return false;
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of Jquery do you have? Jquery 2.x does not support IE8 or below if you have that.

Comment: i have 1.10.2@OpuLance

Comment: still debug it. and found out the undefined value was the one after the last valid object in the list. IE 8 has problem reading the last object

Comment: Is this resource available online some place for direct testing?